# What is considered "well-received" for Polymath?

Tags: support, winter-bash, winter-bash-2016

The [description for Polymath](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/polymath) is:

> post at least one well-received answer on three different sites during Winter Bash (not including Stack Overflow)

What is considered "well-received"?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**An answer with at least a net score of 1** is considered "well-received" for Polymath and would award the hat.