# Understanding Inquisitive Silver badge

Tags: support, badges

The Inquisitive silver badge [description](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/243/inquisitive) reads:

> Ask a well-received question on 30 separate days, and maintain a positive question record.

Please correct me if I am wrong, I interpret the latter part as maintaining a score of greater than or equal to one, but how is *well-received* defined? I could not find any details about it on the linked badge description page.

I see this badge available on lot of other SE sites, but never understood completely how it works. Also, does the interpretation of the definition applies similarly on all the sites or could differ between the sites?

Comment: Related: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26711/how-to-earn-the-inquisitive-badge and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262814/whats-the-meaning-of-well-received-question-and-of-maintaining-a-question and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/288777/what-is-considered-well-received-for-polymath/288778